# What is the mechanism behind ventilatory acclimatization?

Tags: physiology, respiration

In my respiratory physiology lectures, my professor explained that hypoxia-induced hyperventilation occurs in 2 stages when people try to acclimate at high altitudes. **My question is about the long-term 2nd stage, listed as #2 below:**

1. there's an immediate increase in alveolar ventilation triggered by peripheral chemoreceptors, but this only leads to a small increase, and also decreases levels of $p_{CO_2}$.
2. over 8 hrs, there's a slow rise and 2 mechanisms are involved:
   a) bicarbonate ion ($\ce{HCO_3^-}$) in cerebrospinal fluid is shuttled out and chemoreceptors increase their sensitivity to $p_{O_2}$
   b) kidneys excrete more $\ce{HCO_3^-}$ to normalize blood pH

I get that the $\ce{HCO_3^-}$ and $\ce{H^+}$ comes from $\ce{H_2CO_3}$ being broken down through carbonic anhydrase. **But she never mentioned where the $\ce{HCO_3^-}$ is shuttled to or which chemoreceptors are increasing their sensitivity to $p_{O_2}$** (I assume peripheral since it's mentioning sensitivity to $\ce{O_2}$). She then says that because of this $\ce{H^+}$ and $\ce{CO_2}$ levels increase, stimulating central chemoreceptors to increase ventilation to help decrease the acidity/$\ce{CO_2}$ levels. **I don't understand how $\ce{H^+}$ and $\ce{CO_2}$ levels are even rising because I don't know where the $\ce{HCO_3^-}$ is even going and what it's role is.** This professor is terrible at explaining things, and I'm just so confused at this point! Any sort of direction would be so helpful! Thanks!

Comment: not a complete answer, just a comment: $CO_2 + H_2O$ <--> $H_2CO_3$. This is going on all the time (e.g. in a soda bottle) without the need for an enzyme.

Comment: Some links might help you: http://fblt.cz/en/skripta/vii-vylucovaci-soustava-a-acidobazicka-rovnovaha/7-acidobazicka-rovnovaha/ http://www.ccmtutorials.com/renal/Acid%20Base%20Balance%20in%20Critical%20Care%20Medicine-NELIGAN.pdf http://mcat-review.org/excretory-system.php

Answer (score -1):

@Michael Kunh **Carbonic anhydrase** is used in the human body to tip the balance of the reaction  $H_2CO_3\rightleftharpoons H^++HCO_3^-$ to the right side, and is an important player in acidobasic homeostasis.

To answer the question:

$HCO_3^-$ is excreted through the kidneys. This represents the metabolic compensation to respiratory alkalosis that appears in altitude.

To summarize:

1. ascension leaves us in with a **lower partial pressure of oxygen**. This will **stimulate the peripheral chemoreceptors** of the carotid bodies and aortic arch to increase ventilation (hypoxic ventilatory response). In consequence, an **acute respiratory alkalosis** develops.
2. renal adaptation begins after more or less 8 hours, and reestablishes homeostasis after 24-48h. To do that, the kidney will excrete $HCO_3^-$, which will tend to acidify blood (metabolic acidosis to counterbalance respiratory alcalosis). To accelerate this phase, one could take some **acetazolamide**, a diuretic drug that causes $HCO_3^-$ excretion.

Comment: Please note that enzymes do **not** tip the balance of any reaction in a direction. They specifically speed up reactions that are already thermodynamically favourable.